# How to list also two lines after a grep match?

Tags: command-line, scripts, grep, dash-shell

```
grep 'STRING' filename
```

searches the file for STRING and lists the lines that contain a match.
How can I also list two lines that follow the match?

Comment: Use the "-A" flag. More detailed answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081/grep-a-file-but-show-several-surrounding-lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
grep -A 2 'STRING' filename
```

lists the matching lines and two lines that follow the match.